# How to run a c program in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: c, sublimetext2

There are no problems while building, and a message at the bottom line says "Building finished"...but when I try to run it, this message appears:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'bash', u'-c', u"g++ 'D:\\Apps\\hello.c' -o 'D:\\Apps/hello' && 'D:\\Apps/hello'"]]
[dir:  D:\Apps]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vodafone\Vodafone Mobile Broadband\Optimization Client\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\;D:\Apps]
[Finished]
```

and I'm still new to Sublime Text 2.

Comment: what does the windows equivalent of `ls -lR D:\Apps` give you? I just noticed that the `bash` command is operating on `D:\Apps/hello`, not `D:\Apps\hello` as it *should* be. Could it be that simple?

Comment: Please post your build file.

Comment: @AGS - this is the default `C++.sublime-build` that comes with ST2. I don't know why there's a `bash` command in there. It's fixed in ST3.

Comment: @MattDMo yes, when I tried ST3 it worked.

Comment: @AGS I'm sorry the problem is fixed and the old build file is overwritten.

Comment: @mfabel I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, but the problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file in Sublime with the following content:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],

    "variants": [

        {   
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

On the 2nd line, change the name of `mingw32-g++.exe` to whatever `g++` is on your system - possibly just `g++.exe`. Save the file in the `User` subdirectory of your `Packages` folder (which should be in `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2`) as `new_g++.sublime-build`. When you select this build system as your default (`Tools -> Build System -> new_g++`), hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will compile your program, and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will execute it. `start` is the command to start running a separate process, `cmd` is short for `cmd.exe`, the Windows command line program, and the `/k` option keeps the resulting window open after your program exits so you can see its output, run additional commands, or what have you.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to vote this answer up but I still don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: I think that ST is great but it disappointed me today with another problem,as I wrote a very simple c code with a scanf function embedded into it..to see how ST handles user inputs but disappointingly it seems that ST doesn't support user inputs. any suggestions for this problem!.

Comment: @ManaOttman - if my answer helped you, just click on the check mark next to it. It will mark your question as answered, and will help future visitors who may have a similar problem.

Comment: @ManaOttman - in regards to your second comment, unfortunately neither version of Sublime directly supports user input, whether it's `scanf` in C, `raw_input()` in Python, `gets` in Ruby, or any other language. For interpreted languages, you can use [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), and for compiled ones the build system I suggested in my answer will work just fine through `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Actually, technically that isn't completely true, there are ways for plugins to interact with users via the Python API, but direct input is not supported.